# Последняя строка дважды выбирается из курсора

Tags: oracle, plsql

Имеется такой код на PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
    v NUMBER := 400;
    CURSOR get_tests IS
           SELECT * FROM test_table
           WHERE id < v;
    gt get_tests%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN get_tests;
    LOOP
      FETCH get_tests INTO gt;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Data: ' || To_char(gt.id) || ' ' || To_char(gt.numbers));
      EXIT WHEN get_tests%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE get_tests;
END;
```

В цикле дважды выводится последняя строчка. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В цикле дважды выводится последняя строчка. Почему?

Потому, что сначала выводится значение из курсора, а только потом проверяется, были ли данные извлечены. Переместите проверку на наличие данных сразу после `FETCH` и данные перестанут дублироваться -

```
FETCH get_tests INTO gt;
EXIT WHEN get_tests%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Data: ' || To_char(gt.id) || ' ' || To_char(gt.numbers));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Сергей1991 Если ответов вас устроил, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от текста).